# Installing Steam on Raspbian won't work

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

I recently got my raspberry pi 4, and one of the first things I tried to do was install the Godot Game Engine, but I couldn't get the engine installed for some reason. So then I tried getting steam so I could install it from there. So I downloaded the .deb package from the steam website, and when I run the file, it gives me the following error message:

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages:
        xterm, libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1:i386, libc6:i386

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
E: Unable to locate package libgl1:i386
E: Unable to locate package libc6:i386
Press return to continue:
```

If somebody knows how I can fix this, please let me know.

Comment: You can run "Steam Link" on a Raspberry Pi, but you can't run plain Steam. https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/dont-forget-about-steam-link-on-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 2):

That's because [Steam does not support](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/4061) the ARM architecture the processor of the pi uses, the i386 indicate that those .deb files are for a Intel/AMD processor.